# What does this regular expression mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, I would like to know what does this expression do when you have a list of data in the database?

```
$st =~ s/st_//g
```

what does this mean?

Comment: Look it up in the manual: [`man perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/_PATTERN_/_REPLACEMENT_/msixpodualngcer).

Answer (score 1):

you can easily understand it by printing the value of $st before that and after that:

```
print $st;                #for eg: $st="abc_st_defst_"
$st =~ s/st_//g 
print $st;                #$st="abc_def"
```

So this will replace all the instances of st_ with nothing

Answer (score 0):

> what does this expression do

It substitutes "st_" for "" (i.e. removing it), globally (i.e. as many times as it can).

> when you have a list of data in the database?

What you have in a database is immaterial. It operates on the data in the scalar `$st`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with databases. A simple demonstration shuould help you:

Given...

```
my $st = 'rst_v';
```

When...

```
$st =~ s/st_//g;
```

Then...

```
print $st
```

Yields:

```
rv
```

#### Reference:

- [Substitution and translation](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html)